# Distances between up and down crosses in Gaussian Processes

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, gaussian, estimation-theory

Given a gaussian process $g := \mathcal{GP}\left(\mu, \Sigma \right)$, 
where $\mu$ is the mean and $\Sigma$ is the covariance function, I am interested in estimating the mean value $L_m$ of the distances between up and downcrosses with a constant level $u$, i.e. these distances:

[image]

In this plot, I use $u=0$, but ideally I would like $u$ to be generic. I suspect that this is related with [Rice formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_formula), which estimates the number of upcrosses for a given gaussian process and a given length domain, but I do not know how

Comment: The Brownian motion (started at time $0$ in $0$) changes its sign infinitely often in every neighbourhood of $0$.